# Who am I and where do I live?

Tags: riddle

Everyone loves me, but only the lucky ones can have me.

I'm indestructible, but only with my own family.

Many got killed because of me, serpent being killed to get me but no success until today.

I live underground, but can be seen on earth.

---

This has gone through the [sandbox](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox/5296#5296).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Diamonds?

Everyone loves me, but only the lucky ones can have me.

> Only the rich can afford diamonds but everyone loves them... Girls best friend i have heard!

I'm indestructible, but only with my own family.

> Nothing can scratch a diamond apart from another diamond

Many got killed because of me, serpent being killed to get me but no success until today.

> People fight over diamonds and have killed over them and you can get them from snakes... Or so i have heard!

I live underground, but can be seen on earth.

> Not totally sure on this one, but there are mined from underground, and can be seen in the earth (dirt).

Comment: wouldn't `I'm indestructible, but only with my own family.` mean that it is indestructible only with the family, not indestructible except withing my family

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I was thinking the "only with my own family" part was referring to other rocks/minerals. Diamonds are the highest on the Mohs Hardness Scale so no other rocks can cut diamond, however you can still destroy diamonds through other means

Comment: Yes I can see that making sense then like that

Comment: many things can scratch diamond ... artificial ones ..

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be

> Naag mani(**Cobra Pearl**)

as no one has got success getting it. And as I know there are many who have tried to get it and doing so have lost their lives too. And off course its hard to get,a lucky guy can only get it. And this is a Hindi word I don't know what it is called in English.

Comment: Google Translate translates this as 'Snake gem'.

Comment: @Mithrandir Google gives funny translations. Actually it is called Cobra Pearl in English.

Comment: @ AJ thanks man , its a cobra pearl only.